# python casted memoryview assignment error... why?

Tags: python, memoryview

Due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492716/python-writing-to-memory-in-a-single-operation/53492789#53492789), I need to use python `memoryview.cast('I')` to access a FPGA avoiding double read/write strobe. No panic, you wont need an FPGA to answer the question below...

So here comes a python sample which fails ('testfile' can be any file here -just longer than 20 bytes-, but for me, eventually it will be a IO mapped FPGA HW):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import struct
import mmap

with open('testfile', "r+b") as f:
       mm=memoryview(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 20)).cast('I')

# now try to assign the 2 first U32 of the file new values 1 and 2
# mm[0]=1; mm[1]=2 would work, but the following fails:
mm[0:1]=memoryview(struct.pack('II',1,2)).cast('I') #assignement error
```

The error is:

```
./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
    mm[0:1]=memoryview(struct.pack('II',1,2)).cast('I')
ValueError: memoryview assignment: lvalue and rvalue have different structures
```

I don't undestand the error... what "different structures" are we talking about??

How can I rewrite the right hand-side of the assignment expression so it works??
Changing the left-hand-side will fail for the FPGA... as it seems anything else generates wrong signal towards the hardware...

More generally, how should I rework my array of 32 bit integers to fit the left-hand-side of the assignment...?

Comment: Slices don't include the right endpoint. You need `mm[0:2]`.

Comment: OF course!!!, shame on me! I am swapping between matlab too often and python... Thx @Monica

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Monica is right: The error was simpler than I though. The slice on the left hand side is wrong indeed.